# Remove and blacklist [handler]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, blocklist-request

[handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/handler) feels too generic a term to be useful. Here goes the wiki Excerpt:

> In the Observer pattern, an event handler is the function or method called on an observer listening for an event dispatched by the subject. Also known as an event listener.

I am not familiar with so-called patterns; does this apply to many of the Questions tagged?

Comment: There is no blacklist. The blacklist is only available to SE developers, and there is a cost, so it is only used in very extreme cases.